# IIS website slow in response when calculation in progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, iis, cpu

I have an IIS website which connects to MySQL. I have a link in the website which do the intensive calculation. When this link is triggered, it uses around 20% of CPU resource. Then, if I click other links, the other links are responding very slow. Until the link that does calculation finished, then other links responding time will resume. I am curious why only 20% CPU is used, but the other links still respond slowly. It seems the calculation link occupies the CPU resource. But isn't it different link are run in parallel, how it should be affected by intensive calculation of one link? How can I improve that, or should I tune something in IIS of my code?

Comment: What is the calculation?

Comment: It gets a formula expression from a database, and run recursive function to calculate the formula.

Comment: Well it sounds like the thread priority of this function is too high and slowing down other server processes. Is there any way to run the computation in a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: I have set the "Maximum worker processes' in the application pool to 16. However, when one link is loading, the other link still need to wait. Seems the request is not dispatched to different worker?

Answer (score -1):

Increase the maximum number of worker processes in your IIS application pool for your website. This will enable the server handle multiple requests at the same time. Below is how.

1. Open IIS Manager and Navigate to Application pools.
2. Right click the application pool for your website and select Advanced Settings.
   [image]
3. In the Advanced Settings Dialog Box under Process Model, change the value of maximum worker processes to 10. [You may enter another number (greater than or less than 10)] 1 is default and means only one worker process will be started to handle all your requests. Meaning that only one request will be processed at a time.
4. Click Ok to save your changes
   [image]
5. Restart your application pool [Not mandatory but advised]
6. Thats all. Your Website should now be able to process multiple requests at the same time

Comment: The IIS worker process is smart enough to host multiple threads to handle incoming requests, so "When the process is executing one request, the other incoming requests are queued and executed one at a time" is simply wrong. Because of the wrong statement, this answer does not provide much insight. Web farms of course can help, but even a single server can handle many requests with proper optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Lex Li, I have done more research on this, updated my answer and the above worked for me

Comment: Increasing "Maximum Worker Processes" is the feature called "web garden" introduced in IIS 6. However, it should not be used in most cases, as switching to web farms is far more feasible. But if we go back the question itself, that this web app was written with improper locking, so the developer should remedy that before changing anything on IIS. Neither web farms nor web garden should be used to hide the exact culprit.

Comment: Thanks about that. But I also put into consideration that the person asking the question might not want to alter anything on the algorithm / code since the code was not provided! This brings me to conclude that using multiple worker processes can actually be of use since I can't offer any advice on the code / algorithm. What do you think?